# Differential Geometry. On the Hypotheses which lie at the Bases of Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In that famous paper http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/Geom/WKCGeom.html, Riemann writes the below.  I get lost at the part in bold.  Can someone explain what he means with an example.  I'm thinking of level-surfaces...

§ 3. I shall show how conversely one may resolve a variability whose region is given into a variability of one dimension and a variability of fewer dimensions. To this end let us suppose a variable piece of a manifoldness of one dimension - reckoned from a fixed origin, that the values of it may be comparable with one another - which has for every point of the given manifoldness a definite value, varying continuously with the point; or, in other words, let us take a continuous function of position within the given manifoldness, which, moreover, is not constant throughout any part of that manifoldness. **Every system of points where the function has a constant value, forms then a continuous manifoldness of fewer dimensions than the given one.** These manifoldnesses pass over continuously into one another as the function changes; we may therefore assume that out of one of them the others proceed, and speaking generally this may occur in such a way that each point passes over into a definite point of the other;

Comment: Level "surfaces" is exactly what he is talking about. In more modern wording, he is saying "if on a manifold $M$, we have a smooth function $f : M \to \Bbb R$, then the sets $f^{-1}(c), c\in \Bbb R$ inherit a submanifold structure from $M$ of codimension $ \ge 1$"

Comment: @PaulSinclair: It's a tiny bit different than that, since they might be singular (say, $f(x,y) = xy$). I'm not quite sure how one would say what he's saying in modern wording.

Comment: @MikeMiller - I interpret the phrase "that the values of it may be comparable with one another" as being intended to disallow that possibility. Though possibly instead, his meaning for the phrase was that the function is into some linearly ordered set.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Interesting interpretation. (Reading over my comment again, it had the air of knowing what I was talking about. That's definitely not true!)

Comment: @MikeMiller - Without a thorough reading of this and related papers by Riemann in order to pick up a better understanding of how he tended to describe matters (something I am not personally inclined to do), anything we say is something of guess.

Answer (score 0):

After rereading this a bunch of times, I'm fairly certain that he's describing how to construct an arbitrary n-dimensional coordinate system over an n-dimensional manifold.

The most confusing part is where he introduces the continuous, non-constant function of position (1) and in the next sentence starts off about points where that function is constant (2).  It sounds like a contradiction.

But when I think of how this must apply to an ordinary Euclidean 2D plane with Cartesian coordinates, I imagine (1) to be like walking from the origin along some radial line and recording the x coordinate at each point, and then walking along another radial line and doing the same.  After walking all radial lines I can then draw lines thru sets of points (2) where I discovered the same x coordinate, and those are the grid lines of the x axis.